# Web Setup Wizard breaks after 2.2 update

Tags: magento2.2

After running the latest upgrade to 2.2 via the Web Setup Wizard, it appears to successfully complete the installation. However, when I visit the Web Setup Wizard now, it displays a broken page. Click on the link display a 404.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Okay, whilst continuing to Google this issue, it seems to have been resolved. It looks like I caught the server in limbo between cron tasks. It's been 10 minutes since I refreshed the page and now it works.

Alternatively, this could be a cookie issue. So I suggest completely clearing browser cookies after upgrade.

Sorry, I can't be more technical with an answer.